# Dealing with user control readbility

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a custom user control that I have created for tracking time entries.  The control consists of two panels in a table layout. The first panel contains the labels/name/user info, the second panel contains the data entry textboxes.  This control at runtime is added to a flow layout panel in a form, which is contained inside a table layout panel for sizing reasons. Because of possible differences in resolution and screen sizes, I have set the autoscroll property of the flow layout panel to true. I do get the scrollbars when the control is being cut off so this works as expected.

The only issue so far is with readability. For example:

[image: Form Example with Control]

As depicted in the attached image, the username is populated in the top-left hand corner. If you need to scroll right, you cannot see the name in the left-most panel. I would like to be able to show the username on some empty space at the bottom of the control. I imagine something like this could work (mockup):

[image: Form Example Mockup]

Or I would like the ability to keep the left most panel static. Right now the flow layout panel is handling the autoscroll, which I think should be handled differently (meaning the form size should force the control to auto-scroll only the second panel, and leave the first panel intact, but this may mean that only that individual control can scroll?). What do I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered the usage of a `Splitcontainer` and its `SplitterDistance/FixedPanel property`

[MSDN - Link](https://www.google.be/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDcQFjAB&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx&ei=HntrU87aCsut7QavmICwBQ&usg=AFQjCNHA52xAY0cB6yv8XR26QpkWPjW_Jg&sig2=5zjyFego42MdcshgFvp-0A)

[Another Usefull link](http://www.functionx.com/vb/controls/splitcontainer.htm)

here is a good 'Tutorial':

[Splitcontainer tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/splitcontainer-in-C-Sharp/)

The `Fixedpanel` property isn't discussed though. The Fixed panel should be set to the Panel that `isn't supposed to change`. In your case, you would point to panel on the left hand side.

Comment: I changed the controls to exist in the SplitContainer and I have set Panel1 to be the fixed panel.  I also set auto-scroll to true on the second panel.  When I add to the control to the FlowLayoutPanel on my form, then size the form width down, panel2 does not get any scroll bars.

Comment: So if get it right then Panel1 contains: 'jhon Doe EID....' and Panel2 purely contains its 'Hours'?

Comment: This is correct.  I then add this control to my winform which contains a flow layout panel nested in a table layout panel.  When I resize the right handle of the form smaller than the contents of the control, I expect panel2 to show scroll bars and keep panel1 static, or I would like to show the name in panel1 in some empty space once the name scrolls out of view.  Enabling auto-scroll on the flow layout panel scrolls the entire control when the right form handle is resized and not just panel2.

Comment: This may be a limitation of using one control in the flow layout panel, instead of (for example) a table layout nested in the flow layout panel which takes two control in two columns?  I guess that way I should then be able to make that second column autoscroll contents.  But this is more complex than just adding a control to the flow layout panel

Comment: Quite odd. Normally the scrollbars would come automatically. Could you try the following: Add a flowlayoutpanel to panel2. Add to controls (for his hours) to that flowlayoutpanel inside panel2 (with the property Dock = Fill)?

Comment: Actually they do come automatically if the control is sized smaller than the panel2 contents.  What I am looking for, is the form is sized smaller, to enable the panel2 to scroll.

Comment: Chosen as answer since it is close to the solution that I need.  I think ultimately I was looking at it from the wrong way in regards to control scrolling vs form scrolling.